# How do I find the right NuGet package for my framework version

Tags: nuget, nugetgallery

I need the `Microsoft ASP.Net Web Pages` NuGet package, but I need the version which targets .net 4.0
How do I figure this out? 
Is there a way to figure this out for any given NuGet Package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The later versions of the Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages NuGet package only support .NET 4.5

The older version 2.0.30506.0 supports .NET 4.0

To figure this out I used the [NuGet Package Explorer](http://npe.codeplex.com/), displayed the list of package versions and opened a few of the NuGet packages to see what .NET frameworks they support. As far as I am aware you cannot get the supported .NET frameworks from the metadata returned by the nuget.org OData feed. The only way I know is to look inside the NuGet package itself.