# How do I search for Nuget Packages that target my plaftform?

Tags: .net, nuget, asp.net-core, nuget-package, .net-core

I am looking for a CRON-like timer/scheduler library that can run on Net Standard 1.x (actually it is a simple portable ASP.NET Core web app).

But I couldn't find any way to filter NuGet Packages by target platform. Whatever I tried I always get a list of all the packages, targeting whatever platform, so I am forced to try each one until I find one that doesn't fails on NuGet Restore.

For example:

- I went to nuget.org and did some [trivial search](https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=netstandard%20cron), but seems like there is no way to filter on the target platform.
- I also tried `Visual Studio 2015 Update 3` intellisense on the project.json file, but the suggested packages target other platforms and I end up with build errors.
- Downloaded [NuGet Package Explorer](https://github.com/NuGetPackageExplorer/NuGetPackageExplorer) which is great to find the target platforms of a given package, but doesn't let me search packages by platform.

I know this is a related question:
[ [How do I find the right NuGet package for my framework version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22975738/how-do-i-find-the-right-nuget-package-for-my-framework-version) ], but that question ended up being about how to find the correct older version of a well-known package that targets an older version of .NET Framework.

How can I list or search for NuGet Packages that target `netstandard`?

Comment: As the other comment shows, you have to search for .NET Framework once via Google and then check their packages to see whether they support certain .NET Standards.

Answer (score 1):

As of July 2016, **it is not supported by NuGet**:

"We don't yet support filtering the list in VS this way." [Github issue link](http://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/3156)

Comment: I will not accept my own and negative answer, hopping someone will came up with some way to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Even though Nuget Does not support Filtering Based on Frame work as of now . But even nuget search results is also not that dynamic.
so  Better go for the Google site Search of nuget site which gives better/ different search result than the nuget search like below

in the google search bar enter your search query like this

{your search query here(expecting nuget package with Flatform name)} site:nuget.org

start with the your serach query endind with the SITE:NUGET.ORG

It will definitely gives Different Results which might help you in filtering